# Having Issue on Setting a Hallow Button in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can I yo please take a look at [This Demo](http://www.bootply.com/tQDlnJ0k2y) and let me know how I can get rid of the grey background color on click and after click on the button? I tried this by doing

```
.btn-hallow:hover{
    background: none;
    color: aliceblue;
}

.btn-hallow.active:focus{
    background: none;
   }
.btn-hallow:active:focus{
    background: none;
   }
```

but still getting the grey background as:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `btn-default` from your `btn-group`